# Tastypie - Profile as Nested Resource

Tags: django, tastypie

I am trying to add the profile data inside the UserResource but I cannot find the way to do it.

I tweaked a little the code found on the [docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html), like this:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    profile = fields.ForeignKey(UserProfile, 'profile', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']

        #authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()

    def dispatch(self, request_type, request, **kwargs):

        kwargs['profile'] = request.user.get_profile()
        return super(UserResource, self).dispatch(request_type, request, **kwargs)
```

But is giving me this error:

```
error_message: Cannot resolve keyword 'profile' into field. Choices are: date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password...
```

Any idea of how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd make sure you're using a `ProfileResource` and not just a model. Second that `User.profile` resolves to the profile. So maybe something like:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    profile = fields.ForeignKey('myapp.api.resources.ProfileResource', 'profile', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']

        #authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```